# If statement is not right and not redirecting to correct page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window.location

I'm trying to get a submit button working with some JavaScript functionality but cannot seem to get the right results.

On the page heating-pull.php I have a schedule button which when clicked prompts the user to write a day of the week. When clicked it opens up a prompt box.

```
function show_prompt()
{

    var day=prompt("For Which Day?");
    var startTime=prompt("The Start Time?");
    var endTime=prompt("The End Time?");

    if (day=="Monday" || "Tuesday" 
                      || "Wednesday" 
                      || "Thursday" 
                      || "Friday" 
                      || "Saturday" 
                      || "Sunday")
    {   
        alert("Your Schedule Has Been Set");
    } else
        alert("Scheduling Error, Try Again.")

    window.location ="heating-pull.php";

}
```

If they write a correct day of the week I want them to go to the page where I'm sending them (schedule.php), if they do not enter a correct day I want to reload the page and not let them past.

New to JavaScript and I don't know whats wrong even though I've looked for the answers in this place. Any help would be great. Cheers.

Comment: Don't you want to send the selected day of the week to `schedule.php` ? Also read a book!

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to get the validation working then send whatever is in the prompt to another page.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition in the if statement is not correct. Use this instead

Use

```
if (day == "Monday" || day == "Tuesday" || day == "Wednesday" || day == "Thursday" || day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday") {
    //Do something
};
```

***OR***

```
if (["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"].indexOf(day) > -1) {
    //Do something
};
```

### EDIT

As per comment ***I want the redirect to refresh the page so the user has to fill out the form again.***

You should use

```
 window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

***OR***

```
 document.location.reload(true);
```

The [**Location.reload()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) method Reloads the resource from the current URL.

### EDIT 2

*Complete Code*

```
function show_prompt() {
    var day = prompt("For Which Day?");
    var startTime = prompt("The Start Time?");
    var endTime = prompt("The End Time?");
    if (day == "Monday" || 
        day == "Tuesday" || 
        day == "Wednesday" || 
        day == "Thursday" || 
        day == "Friday" || 
        day == "Saturday" || 
        day == "Sunday"
    ) {
        alert("Your Schedule Has Been Set");
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    } else {
        alert("Scheduling Error, Try Again.")
        window.location = "heating-pull.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you Satpal, I want the redirect to refresh the page so the user has to fill out the form again.

Comment: I copied your code over but it still goes to the schedule page rather than just reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations first.

When using a `if` statement, the `||` doesn't mean something like this:

```
x is equal to 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9
```

Where x would be one of them. The `||` is used to separates conditions:

```
condition1 or condititon2 or contition3
condition1 || condition2 || condititon3
```

In your code you have the first condition right:

```
day=="Monday" = condition1
"Tuesday" = condition2
...
"Sunday" = conditionN
```

In javascripts `Strings` only empty strings evaluate to false. So we can rewrite your condition like this:

```
day=="Monday" || true || true || true || true ...
```

If you want to use `&&` and `||`, you'll have to have conditions between them. But sometimes it's worth using data structures to find something.

In your cases you could have something like

```
// Make this as global as possible but not in window obviously
DaysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
// Freeze the object so nothing can modify it later... you wouldn't want to end up
// with "Caturday" instead of "Sunday"
Object.freeze(DaysOfTheWeek);

function show_prompt()
{

    var day=prompt("For Which Day?");
    var startTime=prompt("The Start Time?");
    var endTime=prompt("The End Time?");

    if(DaysOfTheWeek.indexOf(day) >= 0) {
      // more cod goes here
      window.location = "schedule.php";
    } else {
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
}
```